# DomainEventPublisher consistency

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

Having just read Vaughn Vernon's [effective aggregate design](http://dddcommunity.org/wp-content/uploads/files/pdf_articles/Vernon_2011_2.pdf), I'm wondering about failures related to event publishing.

In the given example at page 9 (page 3 of the PDF), we call `DomainEventPublisher.publish()`. The event being published allows other aggregates to execute their behaviours.

What I'm wondering is: What happens if `DomainEventPublisher.publish()` fails ? What happens if `DomainEventPublisher.publish()` succeeds, but the transaction fails ?

How implementations handle these two cases ?

Comment: The Author answers this in the next paragraph. `What happens if the subscriber experiences concurrency
contention with another client, causing its modification to
fail? The modification can be retried if the subscriber does
not acknowledge success to the messaging mechanism. The
message will be redelivered, a new transaction started, a
new attempt made to execute the necessary command, and
a corresponding commit. This retry process can continue
until consistency is achieved, or until a retry limit is...`

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu: No, I was speaking about publishing the event, not handling it :)

Comment: that example is not very resilient/usable in the real world. The most reliable patterns are those from the Event sourcing, when the events are not published at all but are pulled from the Event store and the  event consumer (the readmodel or saga)  keeps track if the processed events.

Comment: @plalx’s solution seems quite resilient to me. Are you aware of any issue with it ?

Comment: it uses transactions; it makes the Aggregate dependent of the infrastructure (which can be mitigated by returning the events instead)

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu Whether you return them or use a static thread-bound synchronous `DomainEventPublisher` you pretty much get the same exact result with the same testability. The pattern does use database transactions, but the domain is not aware of these in any way. I don't really see your point.

Comment: @plalx the Aggregate makes an `IO` call and I don't like that. I keep my Aggregates pure, with no side effects, with no dependency to Infrastructure or any other Components in fact.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu Well, they don't make an IO call if there's no registered handler that does IO, which means everything can be unit tested without any IO going on. The ARs themselves have no dependencies on infrastructure components or any other packages.

Comment: @plalx but they do, it's the `DomainEventPublisher`

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu  The `DomainEventPublisher` is a domain component, which lives in the domain and does in-memory publishing of events without any IO. You may not like the idea of a static class, but in the end it doesn't add any restrictions or practical drawbacks compared to returning events or recording them in a collection on the AR. The only issue I see is that if the `DomainEventPublisher` has a bug then tests could fail, but I don't see how that's a problem in any way, considering it's not a component that will ever change anyway.

Comment: @plalx `DomainEventPublisher` is Infrastructure that lives in the Domain. The Aggregates should not depend on Infrastructure. The Sagas or Readmodels may depend on the Infrastructure because they need to but Aggregates don't (because there are other ways to do it). This is my personal opinion.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu Sagas and Readmodels wouldn't depend on `DomainEventPublisher`, they would depend on durable messaging infrastructure, which isin't what `DomainEventPublisher` is. It's just an in-memory publish-subscribe implementation that has a UL-driven interface, a helper class. I guess you could conceptually consider this as infrastructure, but that's just hair splitting given it has not really any actual negative impact on the model & system flexibility (at least not any that I can think of right now). It's not like if the AR would depend on NServiceBus.

Comment: @plalx is the Persistence (database) reached in the `DomainEventPublisher.publish()` call?

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu Not if there's no subscriber to do so, which you'd only register in the context of a running application. As far as the `DomainEventPublisher` is concerned, it publishes events to an in-memory list of subscribers. You can have a look at a [sample implementation here](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_common/src/main/java/com/saasovation/common/domain/model/DomainEventPublisher.java).

Comment: @plalx I will, thanks

Comment: The transactional boundary must be just ONE aggregate. You should not need a transaction that implies two or more aggregates. You sometimes need a transaction to persist business changes done by an aggregate because the business change span changes in multiple elements in persistence; i.e. two or more tables on a relational database.

Comment: @jlvaquero I'm not so sure how your comment is relevant in the above discussion? Your comment was in response to what exactly? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DomainEventPublisher.publish()` is synchronous. You'd setup a [generic handler (handles all events)](https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/05d95572f2ad6b85357b216d7d617b27359a360d/iddd_identityaccess/src/main/java/com/saasovation/identityaccess/application/IdentityAccessEventProcessor.java) which stores the events in the **same database transaction** as the business process, which means your event storage must have the ability to be transactionnal with whatever other storage mechanism you rely on to store the state of your aggregates.

Once events have been written on disk transactionnaly, you can then put them on a message queue for asynchronous delivery.

> Are there other known ways to do it?

Well, rather than using a static `DomainEventPublisher` you could record events in a collection on the AR, just like in event sourcing and then implement a centralised mechanism to store them (e.g. transaction hooks, using aspects, etc.).

Comment: Thanks. I like this solution. Are there other known ways to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

> What happens if DomainEventPublisher.publish() succeeds, but the
>   transaction fails?

In this case I am against Vernon approach. I prefer to [return the events](https://blog.sapiensworks.com/post/2016/08/19/DDD-Application-Services-Explained) to the application service. This way I can persist the changes performed by the aggregate using a transaction (if needed) and, if everything is Ok, I will publish the event. This also helps to keep the business layer entirely clean and pure.

In a few words; if the transaction fails then no event is raised.

> What happens if DomainEventPublisher.publish() fails?

A domain event **never fails, by business rules**, because it's a notification of things that happened. If an aggregate said Yes to the operation and return a event expressing the business changes; then nothing in the world should say that this operation can not be done or has to be undone.

If the event fails by infrastructure then you need to have the tools to re-raise it (automatically or manually) when the outage is fixed and eventually archive the consistency in your system. Take a look at [NServiceBus](https://particular.net/nservicebus). It provides retries, error queues, logs and so on to never loose the events.
If the message system is down you have at least event logs that you can use to re-rise them into the message system.

Comment: Thanks. I think that my question was not clear enough about the things that can fail: The first thing is that we can fail to pulish an event (e.g. the messaging system is down temporarily). The second thing is that after publishing an event, the ongoing transaction can fail to commit; as a result, we have published an event, but the thing didn't really happen since the transaction failed.

Comment: But I am answering that 2 things. What do you do not understand in my answer that drives you to think that I misunderstood your question?

Comment: I'm speaking about *publishing* events, not about *handling* them :)

Comment: And my answer is that changing Vernon strategy allows you to publish the events when the transaction commits or not publish them when transaction fails.

Comment: `"I can persist the changes performed by the aggregate using a transacion (if needed) and, if everything is Ok, I will publish the event"` That makes no sense, given events and the state of the ARs have to be stored atomically. The way you just described would allow for a very inconsistent system. What if the transaction commits, but publishing the event fails?

Comment: @plalx it is called eventual consistency. It is a big  buzzword. Im susprised you do not know it. Search google. Now I undersrand why all I say does not have sense to you nor the OP. We are almost speaking differente languajes.

Comment: @jlvaquero I am very well aware of eventual consistency and sagas/process managers. That's not what you are describing. What you are saying is that you may only raise and commit events AFTER a successful transaction. That's wrong, plain and simple. Events must ALWAYS be persisted in the same transaction as the transaction in which the AR state was modified.

Comment: @plalx Nope. Events are collateral efects. The aggegate is the transaction boundary and once the aggregate changes are persisted the bounded contex consistency is in a good state. The others BC will eventually consisten through the events. A transaction should not cover more than one BC.

Comment: @jlvaquero I dont think you understand what we are saying. We are saying that events should be STORED in the same transaction the AR state is STORED. This has nothing to do with publishing the events on a messaging infrastructure.

Comment: @plalx I you are storing the events in persistence you are doing event sourcing (the OP does not mention event sourcing BTW) so you do not need to store the AR state because the business state is already expressed by the events. My response is how I think things should be done in a NON event sourcing architecture. To avoid loose the events if publishing fails I use the mechanism provided by NServiceBus but you can allways do it by hand. If publishing fails your BC is in a consistent state and you just have to republis the event agan when the outage is fixed.